# What is the practical difference between is_admin() and is_blog_admin()?

Tags: wp-admin, admin, conditional-tags

I can see that the 2 functions are almost identical. Only difference is in one line:

@is_admin()
`return $GLOBALS['current_screen']->in_admin();`

@is_blog_admin()
`return $GLOBALS['current_screen']->in_admin( 'site' );`

What is the practical purpose / reason behind this? Or where can i read more about it?

I can see that `is_blog_admin()` 'born' much later, and since it's giving the 'site' parameter to the `in_admin()` function that it calls internally, it works as a stricter condition, thus being more specific and probably not good idea to use it as an 'alias' to 'is_admin()' (since it's not). I just would like to see where this is used in practice?

Comment: Ok, now I also need to know... ...good find Viktor... ...the Codex shows literally no difference.  Neither is listed as deprecated or perhaps set to be deprecated...  it looks like `is_blog_admin()` was introduced in `3.1.0` where a bunch of `network` related functions were also introduced, so perhaps it relates to multi-site somehow.  (That's just a guess.)

Comment: Yes, i added some more text to the question, please read it too. I'm sure we will find it out shortly. The extra param in `in_admin()` function is the key here. Would be happy to hear the devs who released it. (trac?, github logs?)

Comment: Are you familiar with [WordPress Multisite](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/)? Just from the names I'd guess that `is_blog_admin()` is a bit stricter, checking if the user is an admin for the given site of the network.

Comment: What i found is the Screen class `class-wp-screen.php`, has some already deprecated variables like `$is_network`, `$is_user`, which now can be checked only direclty via the `in_admin()` function. I guess then `is_blog_admin` is a convenience wrapper. Plugins and some themes use it mostly (correct me if i'm wrong) to target the normal (blog level) admin screen and close out the user and network (superadmin) screens. (if i get this right:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a multisite network `is_admin()` is `true` for everything under `/wp-admin`, including the multisite network admin at `/wp-admin/network`, but `is_blog_admin()` is only true for the admin for an individual site/blog on the network, and is *not* `true` for `/wp-admin/network`.